# How to move a WhatsApp account from an Facebook BSP to simple Facebook app?

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapi, whatsapp-cloud-api

I'm using an Facebook WhatsApp BSP "blip".

But I'm building my own WhatsApp App in Facebook and I would like to use this WhatsApp account that is in this BSP above.

But I don't know the properly way to do it because I wouldn't like to lose score, verified status of this account.

I tried to find a way in the Facebook documentation but didn't find any solution.

I will use same WABA account. Is this possible?

Comment: Might it be worth speaking to a Technical Support contact about this?

Comment: I see that "Blip" is a tool that integrates into Facebook/WhatsApp. However this may not be sufficiently well-known that you can rely on this knowledge for your question. You may find it helpful to edit your question to add some context.